# check if two values are meaningfully equal using === not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if two values are meaningfully equal using javascript but it is not working when a button is clicked. Below is my attempt

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(':button').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'click') {
        alert('this button was clicked');

        $('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
        });//trim white spaces

      var name = localStorage.getItem("inputName");

    if(document.getElementById('inputName').value === name ){

    alert('both values are equal'); //but it never gets executed when the two values are equal

}else {
      alert('not showing anything'); //always executing this line
    }

    }else {

    }
});
});
```

how can I execute the if block only when the two values are equal.

Comment: `jQuery(':button')` is not valid. Did you mean `jQuery('button')`?

Comment: BTW `===` is used to check if something is *identical*, not necessarily *meaningfully equal*.

Comment: @AndrewLi but the if block is not executing

Comment: What do you get when you use `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: the else block executes as well

Comment: If you log the values to the console, are they the same? `console.log(document.getElementById('inputName').value, name);`

Comment: oops the second is returning undefined

Comment: @stratedge thanks I have solved my problem

Comment: @Kinduser sure it is a typo

Comment: @parker: Then I suggest editing the title of the question as it does not really have anything to do with the niceties of `===`.

Comment: please suggest for me then

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the value with `.val()` and check which type `var` `name` has

You can do normal comparison `==` for this task or do a checking parse to use `===` instead

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
$('.click').on("click", function() {
  var input = $('#inputName').val();
  var name = "hello";
  if (input == name) {
    alert('both values are equal');
  } else {
    alert('both are not equal');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click" id="click">Click</button>
<input type=text id="inputName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(some.value === name && other.value === eman ) {
  execute();
}
```

That doesn't solve any of the "listener" problems you may have, but that is how you require two conditions to be true (or more if you continue the pattern).

Also, || is for "or" conditions.

For specific cases I have used an "additive" solution where both conditions being true sets a variable to '2', just one condition being true setting that variable to 1, and none of the conditions being true sets that variable to 0. That helps when one and only one condition must be true...